# Why is cloning arrays so slow?

Tags: java, performance, clone

This test

```
        for (;;) {
            int[] a = new int[10];
            System.gc();
            long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
//              int[] b =  a.clone();
                int[] b =  Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
        }
```

shows ~50ms for Arrays.copyOf and ~160 ms for clone. Clone is a special native method for making copies, why is it so slow?

I ran the test on my HotSpot Client JVM 1.7.0_11-b21. Note that when the array increases in size, the difference between clone and copyOf disappears.

Comment: `clone` is overloaded (because it must handle both pointer and scalar arrays), and, in the standard Sun/Oracle implementation, likely under-optimized.  I've worked on implementations of `clone` that would most certainly do much better.

Comment: Also note that if you used larger arrays (say 10,000 elements) the numbers would likely be different.

Comment: Here is a reference to a bug you explain: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6428387 -- However you microbenchmark sucks - it's plain wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a good article explaining why clone is slow here http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue124.html. To put it shortly, it's because int[].clone simply uses Object.clone and this method makes two checks before copying the array:

1.Check whether instance is normal object or array.

2.Check whether array is of primitives or objects.

I added these checks to the Arrrays.copyOf test

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            Class cls = a.getClass();
            if (cls.isArray() && !cls.getComponentType().isAssignableFrom(Object.class)) {
                int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
            }
        }
```

and the test showed no difference between clone and Arrays.copyOf. Had it been a specialized version for arrays clone would have been fast.

Comment: `a)` That article is about Java 1.5, it's from 2006. `b)` Even considering their findings, note their conclusion: prefer `clone` to `new`+`arraycopy` because the code is simpler and copying performance is identical. Two simple `if` checks cannot possibly be a cause of performance degradation of any real piece of code.

Answer (score 5):

I ran your code on my system: there's virtually no difference between them. Both clock in at about 30 milliseconds. My test is on OpenJDK 7.

To confirm I also ran it through Caliper, and used a larger array to emphasize the actual copying performance:

```
public class Performance extends SimpleBenchmark {
  final int[] source = new int[1000];

  public int timeClone(int reps) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = reps; i > 0; i--)
      sum += source.clone().length;
    return sum;
  }

  public int timeCopyOf(int reps) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = reps; i > 0; i--)
      sum += Arrays.copyOf(source,source.length).length;
    return sum;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Runner.main(Performance.class, args);
  }
}
```

Result:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Clone} 2141.70 ns; σ=5416.80 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=CopyOf} 2168.38 ns; σ=1545.85 ns @ 10 trials

benchmark   us linear runtime
    Clone 2.14 =============================
   CopyOf 2.17 ==============================

vm: java
trial: 0
```

Per request, here it is with array size 10:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Clone} 30.07 ns; σ=2.12 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=CopyOf} 29.34 ns; σ=161.38 ns @ 10 trials

benchmark   ns linear runtime
    Clone 30.1 ==============================
   CopyOf 29.3 =============================
```

Comment: There is the possibility, that the complete loop is removed my the compiler. The cloned array points to an unused local variable. I am not sure, if the bytecode will contain that loop.

Comment: I ran the test on my HotSpot Client JVM 1.7.0_11-b21

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach HotSpot wouldn't dare eliminate a whole method call because it may have side-effects.

Comment: @Marko can you rerun your test with array size = 10?

Comment: I talk about the *.java -> *.class compiler. Not the HotSpot compiler, which compiles the the *.class to native code. The javac can determine sideeffects in a lot of cases. That compiler can flatten loops and do some other optimizations. But I just read, that the javac does not make many optimizations, because that will cause problem in the HotSpot.

Comment: If I read this article correct, the Hotspot could remove the complete loop becuase of dead-code removal. You have changed the code in that case, that the lenght of the copied or cloned arrays are summed to a variable. I think this would make the cloned / copied code life-code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I don't think HotSpot ever removes method calls, except maybe for some very narrow special cases. No method call is dead code; it may just so happen that the method is a) final/effectively final so not subject to dynamic dispatch and b) has no side-effects. Only if you can prove both of those can you remove the call.

Comment: @Marko You used int[1000] this is why there's no difference, make it 10 or better 1. Actually I've found an explanation here http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue124.html.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Did you see the last part of my answer, which I added at your request? It's using `int[10]`.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev I actually ran the code from the page you link to and these are the results: `clone(): 837 arraycopy(): 784`. Quite in line with my findings. Beware of old web content on Java performance, that one is from the days of Java 1.5!

Comment: Here is some proof,  no need to test it: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6428387

Comment: Nice link, @bestsss. So it was fixed back in 2007.